# how to save radio buttons value in mysql from laravel

Tags: laravel, database, radio-button

i have below code in my laravel blade:

```html
<div class="stars">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
</div>
```

when i use  `dd($request->all())`
it returned these line:

```
array:4 [▼
    "inputstar" => "11"
    "star" => "on"
    "products_id" => "84"
    "products_review" => "aaaaaa"
]
```

this code is for getting star rate

now , how to save radio buttons value in mysql from laravel code?

Comment: Star buttons need to have an integer value. So when you post it, you know the rating submitted from the user. You can also have `enum` as the datatype column for this rating for more robust design.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting "on" because you haven't specified a value for your inputs. just add a value to each of your input fields and the form will return the given value for each input.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your form as below:

```
<div class="stars">
@for($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)
  <input class="star star-{{$i}}" id="star-{{$i}}" type="radio" name="star" value="{{$i}}"/>
  <label class="star star-{{$i}}" for="star-{{$i}}"></label>
@endfor
</div>
```

Now, if you `dd($request->all());` it should give you the value of star instead of the text `on`.

Comment: You are most welcome. If this answer solves your problem, then don't forget to approve the answer.